# Even if granted all permission not going to mainactivity from splashactivity. permission should be asked until granted

Tags: java, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions, splash-screen

'''coding as follows In Splash Activity I have added permission which will ask again and again until the permission granted but even if I grant every permission it is not going to the main activity. I have left a blank method of what to do if the permission is denied inside the CheckPermission method. And I don't want to use the usual splash screen method of splashing the screen for a few seconds I want to stay in that page until all the permission is granted.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 

private TextView tv;
private ImageView iv;
boolean haveConnectedWifi=false;
boolean haveConnectedMobile=false;
boolean gps_enabled=false;
boolean network_enabled=false;
myTravelAdapter mTA;


public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10; // code you want.

String[] permissions= new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_activty);
    CheckPermission();
    haveNetworkConnection();
    locationAlert();
    NetworkAlert();




}

// FOR CHECKING PERMISSIONS

public boolean CheckPermission() {
    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p:permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this,p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );

        return false;
    }
    return true;

}




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissionsList[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:{
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                String permissionsDenied = "";
                for (String per : permissionsList) {
                    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                        permissionsDenied += "\n" + per;

                    }

                }
                // Show permissionsDenied


            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void updateView() {

}


public void NetworkAlert() {
    if(!haveConnectedWifi  && !haveConnectedMobile){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Please check your internet Connection.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Please turn on your Wifi or Mobile Data to use Helmet 2020", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }else {
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Set a title for alert dialog
        builder.setTitle("");

        // Ask the final question
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to reject call wile driving?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when user clicked the Yes button
                ActivityFlag.reject_call=true;
                serverMain.getInstance().start();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when No button clicked
                ActivityFlag.reject_call=false;

                serverMain.getInstance().start();


                if(CheckPermission()){



                  Intent i = new Intent (SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i); finish();
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Please give all permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); CheckPermission();

                }
            }
        });

        android.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        // Display the alert dialog on interface
        dialog.show();

    }
}

//FOR CHECKING LOCATION ENABLED OR NOT AND WILL SHOW ALERT DIALOG

public void locationAlert() {
    if( !gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Please enable the location.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Please turn on your location to use Helmet 2020", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

//FOR CHECKING NETWORK STATE AND WILL SHOW ALERT DIALOG

public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length; ++i) {
        String permission = permissions[i];
        if (permission.equals("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") && grantResults[i] == -1) {
            requestPermissions();
            break;
        }
    }

}

public static void requestPermissions() {
    List<String> permissions = checkPermissions();
    if (permissions.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, (String[])permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 0);
    }

}

public static boolean isPermissionGranted(Activity ac) {
    activity = ac;
    List<String> permissions = checkPermissions();
    if (permissions.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
        return false;
    }
}

public static List<String> checkPermissions() {
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") != 0) {
        permissions.add("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        permissions.add("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    }

    return permissions;
}
```

Give Permission on click

```
isPermissionGranted(MainActivity.this);
```